# dynamic search of strings

Tags: java, string

I have an arrayList of string

```
List<String> titleBar = Arrays.asList("UserName*","Dob*", "Email*", "Address","Country");
```

and a bean

```
public class TitleBar {

    String userName;
    String dob;
    String email;
    String adress;
    String country;

    getter and setter for all fields()

}
```

I'm trying to validate the mandatory fields(i.e title items ending with *) 
 I know which fields are mandatory (as I can see the titleBar list) so i can use simple not null check

```
if (userName != null) {
    sysout(please enter username)
}
if (email != null) {
    sysout(please enter Email)
}
```

but My requirement for mandatory fields keeps on changing. 
so each time adding and removing not null check methods will be overhead for me.
So what i want to do is validate the mandatory fields dynamically i.e a method that uses the titleBar list and check all the mandatory fields are not null.
 I'm out of ideas .(collection type can be altered). Just wanted to know what features or API's of Java can be used.

Comment: You need to abstract. Instead of checking individual items, group them. Create some kind of `Set` that holds identifiers for all mandatory fields. Then you should only check the fields that are currently in this set, a generic solution. So instead of having fields like `userName` you could create a class like `Field` that has properties like `isMandatory`.

Comment: @Zabuza: ...or use bean validation...

Comment: Thank you @Zabuka , i'll think in that directon

Comment: @Makoto i tried annotaions also , but my requirement is i shout be able to set the constraints to the bean fields based on the * mark of arrayList items

Comment: It'd be ludicrous, expensive and error-prone to attempt bean validation without actually using bean validation.  These validators have withstood the test of time. Besides, this is a feature/library that Java has which can provide this validation, which satisfies the original question criterion.

Comment: @Makoto, what I meant was  I want to know how can I select the bean fields dynamically so that i can use the bean validation constraints on the mandatory fields (which keeps on changing according to my requirements) hope you are able to understand my question